# Adding wildcard selector on id on input selector?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, wildcard

I have a website that has multiple forms but how do I add the wildcard selector id to the beginning of the input id selector?

My Jquery is as follows:

```
$('[id^=editeventform_]').submit(function(){
    var editevtid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert('Edited: '+ event.target.id);
    alert(editevtid);

    var event_date_edit = $("#event_date_edit").val();
    var event_orig_name_edit = $("#event_orig_name_edit").val();
    var event_orig_tel_edit = $("#event_orig_tel_edit").val();
    var event_orig_email_edit = $("#event_orig_email_edit").val();
    var event_title_edit = $("#event_title_edit").val();
```

I have tried the following but all I get is an undefined alert value.

```
var event_title_edit = $(editevtid + "#event_title_edit").val();
```

Comment: As ID is unique, use `$("#event_title_edit").val();`

Comment: @Tushar - It doesn't work because there are four forms with the same input name and id's, so I want to target the wildcard ID on the input selector?

Comment: Use context selector `$("#event_title_edit", this).val();`

Comment: @Tushar - Many thanks it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**ID should be unique.**

Use [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context), it'll search the passed selector element inside the given context. `this` inside the event handler is the element on which the event has occurred, `form` in this case. So, passing `this` as context will search for the element inside the form that is being submitted.

```
$("#event_title_edit", this).val();
```